# Why is output "True"

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Why this perl code is giving output "True"?

```
$bar = "\\";
if ($bar =~ /[A-z]/){
  print "True";
} else {
  print "False";
}
```

Shouldn't it return false?

Comment: and is it `false` with `$bar =~ /[a-Z]/` ?

Comment: Before you go another step, please take some time to review http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html -- use character classes, preferably named, when possible; it makes things SO much easier for people who follow behind you. In this case, [:alpha:] is probably what you want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because \ is between A-z. See table below, 92 is between 65 and 122. Try [A-Z].

```
   0 nul    1 soh    2 stx    3 etx    4 eot    5 enq    6 ack    7 bel
   8 bs     9 ht    10 nl    11 vt    12 np    13 cr    14 so    15 si
  16 dle   17 dc1   18 dc2   19 dc3   20 dc4   21 nak   22 syn   23 etb
  24 can   25 em    26 sub   27 esc   28 fs    29 gs    30 rs    31 us
  32 sp    33  !    34  "    35  #    36  $    37  %    38  &    39  '
  40  (    41  )    42  *    43  +    44  ,    45  -    46  .    47  /
  48  0    49  1    50  2    51  3    52  4    53  5    54  6    55  7
  56  8    57  9    58  :    59  ;    60  <    61  =    62  >    63  ?
  64  @    65  A    66  B    67  C    68  D    69  E    70  F    71  G
  72  H    73  I    74  J    75  K    76  L    77  M    78  N    79  O
  80  P    81  Q    82  R    83  S    84  T    85  U    86  V    87  W
  88  X    89  Y    90  Z    91  [    92  \    93  ]    94  ^    95  _
  96  `    97  a    98  b    99  c   100  d   101  e   102  f   103  g
 104  h   105  i   106  j   107  k   108  l   109  m   110  n   111  o
 112  p   113  q   114  r   115  s   116  t   117  u   118  v   119  w
 120  x   121  y   122  z   123  {   124  |   125  }   126  ~   127 del
```

Use the following command to see ASCII chart:

```
man ascii
```

Comment: . . . or if the OP wants both upper and lower case, he should try `[A-Za-z]` and not include the extra unwanted chars

Comment: +1 Why I had never have the idea to paste the ascii table! :)

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, could you kindly accept my answer with a lovely big green tick? If not, please say what went wrong so I/someone else can assist you further.

Answer (score 6):

```
$bar =~ /[A-z]/;
```

is not same as

```
$bar =~ /[A-Z]/;
```

Check all chars between `A` and `z`:

```
perl -le 'print map chr, ord("A") .. ord("z")'
```

---

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Becauase you've written `[A-z]`:

See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html

```
[a-z]       #  Matches a character that is a lower case ASCII letter.
```

Try `[A-Z]` for uppercase, or `[a-zA-Z]` for both upper and lower case